# River vs cards in hand

Tags: texas-hold-em, prize-pool

Ok I was playing a game of hold 'em with some friends and something similar to the following scenario came up:

Hand 1:
A,6

Hand 2:
A,2

Table:
2,A,6,9,9

The question is:
Does hand 1 win the pot or is it a split pot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you take the best 5 cards every time

**split the pot**

Hand 1
AA996

Hand 2
AA996

Comment: That's what I was thinking, thanks for the confirmation. My friends are happy with the answer too.